# Teria como criar uma função para diminuir a quantidade de if's do programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Há como fazer uma função que consiga reproduzir essa quantidade de if's  no programa para que eles não apareçam ?

```
mensagem =  ('''
Escolha a conversão que você deseja :
1) Celcius-Fareheint
2) Fareheint-Celcius
3) Celcius-Kelvin
4) Kelvin-Celcius
5) Fareheint-Kelvin
6) Kelvin-Fareheint
''')

try:
   mensagem = float(input(mensagem))
   if mensagem > 6 or mensagem < 0:
       print ("Insira uma opção válida")

except ValueError:
    print ("Escolha uma opção válida")

if mensagem == 1 :
    dado1 = float(input ("Qual é a temperatura ?"))
    resultado = (dado1*1.8+32)
    print (resultado)

if mensagem == 2 :
    dado1 = float(input ("Qual é a temperatura ?"))
    resultado =(5*(dado1-32)/9)
    print (resultado)

if mensagem == 3 :
    dado1 = float(input ("Qual é a temperatura ?"))
    resultado = (dado1 + 273.15)
    print (resultado)

if mensagem == 4 :
    dado1 = float(input ("Qual é a temperatura ?"))
    resultado = (dado1 - 273,15)
    print (resultado)

if mensagem == 5 :
    dado1 = float(input ("Qual é a temperatura ?"))
    resultado = ((dado1 + 459.67)/1.8)
    print (resultado)

if mensagem == 6 :
    dado1 = float(input ("Qual é a temperatura ?"))
    resultado = ((dado1 *1.8)- 459.67)
    print (resultado)
```

Comment: Em muitos casos uma grande quantidade de condicionais poderia ser substituida por uma estrutura de dado do tipo hash table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim é possível, mas antes, eu gostaria de falar sobre algumas melhorias rápidas que você pode fazer no seu código. Primeiro de tudo, não é necessário utilizar os parênteses ao criar a string e ao fazer o cálculo da temperatura.

Segundo, se a opção do usuário não for válida, os `if`'s serão executados mesmo assim, e o usuário deverá abrir novamente o programa para escolher novamente a opção. Então o que você poderia fazer é criar um bloco `while` para o programa repetir a tela de seleção enquanto o usuário não tiver escolhido uma opção válida.

Terceiro, em Python, você deve criar os números reais utilizando um ponto `.` e não vírgula. Um outro detalhe interessante é que, em Python, podemos fazer múltiplas comparações em uma única linha. Assim sendo, podemos transformar `if mensagem > 6 or mensagem < 0` nisso `if not 0 < option < 7`.

Esses foram alguns erros, mas há outros também que você pode ver mais abaixo na resposta.

---

Agora voltando ao foco da pergunta, sim é possível criar uma função para reduzir as condicionais e deixar o código mais bonito e organizado. Veja abaixo:

```
def obterTemperatura(option):
  
    temp = float(input("Qual é a temperatura ? "))
  
    if option == 1:
        return temp * 1.8 + 32
  
    elif option == 2:
        return 5 * (temp - 32) / 9
  
    elif option == 3:
        return temp + 273.15

    elif option == 4:
        return temp - 273.15

    elif option == 5:
        return (temp + 459.67) / 1.8

    elif option == 6:
        return temp * 1.8 - 459.67

try:
    option = int(input(mensagem))
   
    if not 0 < option < 7:
        raise ValueError
      
    print(obterTemperatura(option))
    
except:
    print("Escolha uma opção válida.")
```

No código acima, eu corrigi alguns erros e reutilizei algumas linhas, colocando-as dentro da função `obterTemperatura`. Mas ainda assim, é possível reduzir mais ainda esse código, utilizando dicionários e funções anônimas (lambdas).

Com dicionários, nós podemos obter um valor a partir de uma chave. Então podemos fazer dele uma espécie de "condicional" (você já vai entender essa ideia). O que eu vou fazer é passar as opções de cálculos como chaves do dicionário, e vou criar funções anônimas para cada uma dessas chaves. Veja abaixo como ele vai ficar:

```
def obterTemperatura(option):
  
    temp = float(input("Qual é a temperatura ? "))
    
    calculos = {
        1: lambda temp: temp * 1.8 + 32,
        2: lambda temp: 5 * (temp - 32) / 9,
        3: lambda temp: temp + 273.15,
        4: lambda temp: temp - 273.15,
        5: lambda temp: (temp + 459.67) / 1.8,
        6: lambda temp: temp * 1.8 - 459.67
        }
    return calculos[option](temp)
```

Nessa função, eu criei um dicionário chamado `calculos` que contém chaves de 0 à 6. Em cada uma dessas chaves, existe uma função que irá retornar o resultado do cálculo da temperatura de sua respectiva opção.

Logo, se `option` for `4`, por exemplo, o programa irá obter o valor da chave `4` que será a função `lambda temp: temp - 273.15`, e essa será executada retornando o resultado da função.